# React component is constructed twice on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some react components ,  and I'm using a react-router for routing.

In the App.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    HttpService.get("masterData")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          masterData: response.data.masterData
        })
      .catch(e => {});
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/viewAsset"
           component= {()=> <ViewAssetComponent masterData={this.state.masterData}/> }
          />
        //....
        </Switch>
     </Router>
    )
}
```

But my ViewAssetComponent is constructing two times and componentDidMount also called two times which is not expected.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is due to the rendering method of your component on your `react-router` Route.

According to the official documentation

> When you use the component props, the router uses React.createElement
>   to create a new React element from the given component. That means if
>   you provide an inline function to the component attribute, you would
>   create a new component every render. This results in the existing
>   component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just
>   updating the existing component.”

When the App.js http call completed, App.js will re-render which make the react router to re genereate the component as the component for a route is defined as an inline function. The function will be executed and `<ViewAssetComponent/>` will be constructed again.

So ideally the best way is to put the component with props inside a render props of the `<Route/>`

```
      <Route
        path="/viewAsset"
        render={props => (
          <ViewAssetComponent{...props} masterData={this.state.masterData} />
        )}
      />
```

Which will construct the component only once.